Button click Hyperlinks
I have an Excel workbook which we use as a work report card, with one used per job. Each of these workbooks has photographs which we paste in, resize with a macro then put in place on a specific sheet.
There is no requirement to actually have the photo on display, so I was aiming to implement a simple Button, which when pressed would open the 'Create Hyperlink' dialogue box, so my technicians could simple navigate to the photograph, select and press ok, with the hyperlink then appearing in a cell next to the button.
I have added a photo to show how I would like the layout would look. Does anybody here have a Macro that would do that?
Thanks for any help in advance.
I am not the best at coding or Macros in general, but i have struggled to find anything online which matches my requirements.
Layout

You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.
